# Variable information inside comments in a< Scala XML literal

Tags: scala

As many already know, Scala XML literals, allow to embed in the code in an easy way, XML literals.  By using the `{}` notation, variable information can be embedded.

Example:

```
val something = "SOMETHING"
val xml = <elem>{hello}</elem>
```

My question, is how to embed variable information in a comment.

This doesn't work:

```
val xml = <elem><!-- A comment with {something} variable--></elem>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Scala's `Comment` case class.

```
import scala.xml.Comment

val comment = Comment("A comment with " + something + " variable")
val xml = <elem>{comment}</elem>
```

This will print out:

```
<elem><!-- A comment with SOMETHING variable--></elem>
```

Check out the documentation [here.](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.xml.Comment)

Comment: A little more compact: `val xml = "<elem>{Comment(s"A comment with $something variable")}</elem>`